# Limiting mysql calls for the same information in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm using cakephp but this could potentially apply to any framework / php-based environment.

I have a blogging platform and people can like, share, comment etc. Each of these likes, shares and comments have an associated user and this means that the same user is requested from the database many many times for different things, running this same query:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`fullname`, `User`.`avatar`, FROM `db`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`id` = 127
```

Is there a way that I can stop this from happening, apart from caching? Or does it not really matter that MySQL is doing the same call 5 or more times for the same information?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but you can get current user data array with `$this->Auth->user()` in the controller, or `AuthComponent :: user()` anywhere in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's CAKE way** - to get many simple queries and cache them.

Check Your all `$this->YourModelName->find()` queries - probably You do not use recursive or contain options, so **when You take comments data, CAKE takes related models too** (`hasMany/belongsTo` relations in Your models). You can:

- use `$this->loadModel(YourModelName);` to load model on the fly
- use `$this->YourModelName->Behaviors->attach('Containable');` to attach selected models and fields
- set `recursive => -1` to get data from one model/table only
- use own query with `join` option (it can be one query instead of `contain` or `recursive` option)
- for some data like User data You can storage it in session like `$this->Session->write()`
- if You use Auth component, You can get from auth like `$this->Auth->user('id')`
- always You can set for all models `$useTable = false` and link models on the fly but it's not efficient/economic way (especially when You have to manage Your project in further time)

Answer (score 1):

You can set recursive to -1 on the model, this will cause reads and finds to initially only get the data from that Model unless set on the fly, however, I prefer the containable behavior for reducing queries. You can check that out here.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html